# Django - perform_create() always creates 2 instances

Tags: python, django, database

I have the following `model.py` file:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo =  models.FileField(upload_to='Images/',
                                     default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s%s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )

class Clique(models.Model):

    # holds when the clique was created
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # holds the name of the clique
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    # holds the members of the clique
    members = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

Basically, I have a model for the users and a model for cliques. 
A user can be in multiple cliques and a clique can have multiple users.
What I want is that when a user creates a clique, then he should be automatically added to the clique as member. 
So, in my `views.py` file, I override the `perform_create()` method like this:

```
class CreateClique(generics.CreateAPIView):
    '''
        This class creates a Clique for the user who made the
        request.
    '''

    # define the serializer class 
    serializer_class = CliqueSerializer

    # we use token authentication
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    # user must be authenticated
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user    # get the user
        data = self.request.data    # get the data the user has sent

        # first check if we have the name of the clique
        if 'name' in data:
            name = data['name'] # retrieve the clique name

            clique = Clique.objects.create(name=name)
            clique.members.add(user)


        serializer.save()
```

But when I create a clique (e.g. with name 'Test'), then I have 2 instances of that Clique in my database. I can see that via the shell command:

```
>>> from users.models import Clique
>>> cl = Clique.objects.all()
>>> cl
<QuerySet [<Clique: Test>, <Clique: Test>]>
>>>
```

Why is this happening ? And how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have `Clique.objects.create(name=name)` and also `serializer.save()`, that's the reason you will have two instances.

Basically what you need to do is

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()  # here your object will be created and put in serializer.instance
    serializer.instance.members.add(self.request.user)
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful. But what is serializer.instance ? Is that the serialized Clique object ?

Comment: @abdullahcelik for `CreateAPIView` before `serializer.save()` it's `None`, but after `serializer.save` it will store newly created instance/object of your `Clique` (only if your `CliqueSerializer` inherits `ModelSerializer` and `Meta.model` is `Clique`.)